# Can VBScript run on protected sheet of an Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript, wsh, spreadsheet-protection

I am using VBScript to make lots of calculations on different sheets on the same workbook. Now one concern is if somehow someone deleted any of the sheet, the script would then lead to massive data loss. Is there any way to protect it from users?

Comment: What do you mean by protect from users? Do you not want people to use your workbook? Have you looked into protecting sheets/workbooks?

Comment: @DanielCook I want to lock sheets,but fearing if I would so,shall my scripts can run on those sheets of the workbook?

Comment: Depends what your script is doing. You can retrieve values from a locked sheet no problem. You can also lock the sheet but leave it unlocked for code purposes.

Comment: @DanielCook that's sound good! can i have some idea about locked sheet to open and again lock,when the processing is over,programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

(Make sure you read the edit at the end of this answer)

I have similar workbooks I have made that use sheets like databases, so I understand your concern of protecting the information. If you are protecting the Workbook, it will prevent your macro from performing certain changes to the sheets/book. However, if you only want to protect the sheet contents, you can use the setting UserInterfaceOnly, which will allow your macro to run freely while still protecting the sheets from the users. You can detect if the sheets are protected when opened, and if not, protect them.

```
Sub test()

dim mySheet as worksheet
dim myPass as string

myPass = "password"
set mySheet = Excel.ActiveSheet
if mySheet.ProtectContents = False then
   mySheet.Protect Password:=myPass, UserInterfaceOnly:=True
end if

'Enter your code here

mySheet.Unprotect Password:=myPass

End Sub
```

Furthermore, if you want to give the user the ability to unprotect the sheets after being warned, then you can use Custom UI Editor to remove the protect/unprotect sheets group from the review tab and then replace it with a customized button. I've done this in the past and it actually helped a lot with maintaining the sheets later. I've included a couple links on Custom UI Editor below.

- [Custom UI Editor Download](http://openxmldeveloper.org/blog/b/openxmldeveloper/archive/2006/05/26/customuieditor.aspx)
- [Custom UI Editor Tutorial - Change the Ribbon in Excel 2007 or
  2010](http://www.rondebruin.nl/ribbon.htm)

EDIT:

At first glance I thought this question pertained to VBA (my bad). I believe the above code can still apply, just place the code within the  tags and set the workbook and worksheet variables properly (not the way they are set above). If you don't already know how to set/reference your workbook/worksheetsheet objects, [this forum post](http://www.visualbasicscript.com/VBScript-amp-Excel-m32435.aspx) shows how. Albeit I don't normally work with VBscript, but the forum looks correct. Good luck!

Comment: I am using vbscript to work with Excel,so how and from where I should run the code as you suggested>

Comment: Oh that my fault. I thought it said VBA. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

i nw this was a few years ago, but i ran into it when searching for the answer, hopefully someone fins this helpfull.

First add a password to your workbook that way other users will only be able to open as read only.

http://www.k2e.com/tech-update/tips/728-tips-adding-a-password-to-make-an-excel-workbook-read-only

then to make as part of the vbscript when opening the excel file(s)

```
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set oWorkbook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(file.path,,,,"password","password",True,,True,True)
```

full list of switches can be found here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194819%28v=office.15%29.aspx

hope that helps, took me hours to figure this out.